# Issue with UINotification in iOS / objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsnotifications

I am making an app with different nav controllers. All of them are initially initialized.

Say, I have 3 nav controllers A, B and C.

A View controller from B (say B1) sends a notification that is supposed to be heard from view controller in A (say A1). After that, we go to view controller A1.

However, if we are in the view controller B1 from the beginning (and never went to View controller A1), then A1 doesnt get the notification. However, it gets it the second time.

OR, if I go inside A1 once, then the notifications are properly received.

Can anyone kindly help me out ? Thanks.

NB: the listeners code is in the init of A1. It gets hit (i checked by using breakpoints).

Comment: Can you rephrase your question, its not very clear whether B1 posts notification or listens to notifications.

Comment: @0x8badf00d : B1 posts notifications. A1 listens for those notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're saying the notification is received after the view is displayed once, my suspicion is that you are registering for notifications in a method that isn't run until the view is displayed (`viewDidLoad`, `viewDidAppear:`, etc.).

If this is the case, try moving your notification registration to whichever `init` method that you're using in the ViewControllers.

Comment: I am doing it in the `init` method .. :(

Comment: Hmm. I'm at a loss then. I'll keep thinking though and if I come up with something I'll let you know. If you have any more context or code to post that may help.

Answer (score 0):

NSNotification is observable through all the app.  So, to do what you plan to do, I would use a boolean flag or a counter.  You can put those indicators in the appDelegate class or use a global variables.